# Tag files based on file name if no Title metadata exists

Tags: files, filenames, media, file-metadata

Is there a way using the command line to automatically fill in empty "Title" fields of the tags of music or videos with the file name? I have tried using [Beets](http://beets.io/), but the only way to tag things based on the filename is using the auto-tagger which I don't want use because I need it to be automatic - without user input.

Comment: media metadata of what?

Answer (score 0):

There is [EasyTag](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG) where you can set how to understand file names and directories it is with simple macros. Also you have libs like python-eyed3 which you can use in your scripts, but EasyTag is good enough for home use :)